# View Units sold between 2 different years

Tags: sql

I am trying to view what the sales were for each product between 2 different years. I've been stumped on this for hours now and I am lost on what to do. This is my current code

```
SELECT DISTINCT od.ProductID, SUM(
CASE 
WHEN o.OrderDate between '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-31' THEN od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity 
WHEN o.OrderDate between '2017-01-01' and '2017-12-31' THEN od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity
) as '# of Units Sold' 
FROM OrderDetails od
Inner Join Orders o on od.OrderID = o.OrderID
GROUP BY od.ProductID
ORDER BY od.ProductID ASC;
```

When I run it I get an error because of the incorrect syntax for the case.

I am hoping to get an output like this:

```
Product ID | Units Sold in 2016 | Units Sold in 2017
    1               100                 200
    2                50                  75
```

Help Please??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close:

```
SELECT od.ProductID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.OrderDate between '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-31' THEN od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity
           END) as total_2016,
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.OrderDate between '2017-01-01' and '2017-12-31' THEN od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity
           END) as total_2017
FROM OrderDetails od JOIN
     Orders o 
     ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
GROUP BY od.ProductID
ORDER BY od.ProductID ASC;
```

You need two separate `CASE` expressions, one for each year.